Event study regression specification: interacting covariates with leads and lags
I want to create an event study regression specification for the following:
$$
\ln(y_{ijt}) = \gamma \ln (x_{jt}) + \tau \ln(p_{t}) + \lambda \ln(x_{jt}) * \ln(\mbox{p}_{t}) + \epsilon_{ijt}.
$$
I am not sure if the following would be the correct event study specification:
$$
\ln(y_{ijt}) = \sum_{k=-a}^a\gamma_k \ln (x_{j,t-k}) + \sum_{k=-a}^a \tau_k \ln(p_{t-k}) + \sum_{k=-a}^a \lambda_k \ln(x_{j,t-k}) * \ln(\mbox{p}_{t-k}) + \epsilon_{ijt}
$$
I am interested in the coefficients $\gamma_k$ and $\lambda_k$, and not on $\tau_k$. Should I lead and lag the covariate?
Can someone share some thoughts on if the above event-study specification is correct?

Welcome. I’m not sure why you included three separate summations. Why are the $\lambda_k$’s estimated with interactions and not the $\gamma_k$’s?

@ThomasBilach, thanks for responding. I am just curious how one has the event study specification when there is an interaction term. Example, suppose I am interested at effects of a variable $x$ on a variable $y$ and also want to understand how another variable $p$ modulates this effect. This is my first equation. I now want to recover leads/lags, so want to do an event-study version of the first equation. Not sure how I should get to this. Does this make it clear? Thanks.

I makes more sense. Does $p$ vary over time, but the same for all $j$ units? Is $p$ the indicator for the "event" of interest?

@ThomasBilach Yes, $p$ varies over time but is same for all $j$ units. It is not an indicator for the event. It is a variable which modulates the effect of $x$ on $y$. I want to see how this effect evolves over time, so I want to run a event-study. Does this clarify?

It makes sense. However, I cannot advise you further without more information. Is $x_{jt}$ a binary "event" variable? Do all $j$ units experience the event? And if so, do all $j$ units experience the event in the same time period $t$?

@ThomasBilach thanks for the questions. I have $x_{jt}$ as a continuous variable in one setting, and binary in another. E.g., $x_{jt}$ is once actual tax rate (continuous variable), and in another case it is an indicator variable with value 1 if tax changed in county $j$ and time $t$ (so binary). Some $j$ units experience the event. All $j$ do not experience the event in the same period. Further, event overlaps in some units after certain time. That is, tax changes can happen at several different dates across units and multiple times in a unit over the sample period (in my case, it's 10 yrs).

@ThomasBilach, continued from above: This is bit complemented, and I intend on doing more robust DiD/event-study designs from recent literature. But for this purpose, I am thinking of doing cannonical event-study with interaction. Would this make sense?

As indicated in the comments, $p_t$ is time-varying but exhibits the same pattern across the $j$ units. If you're estimating the standard difference-in-differences equation, adjusting for time effects, then $p_t$ is collinear with those aggregate level temporal shocks. In short, you can safety drop it. The main effect of $p_t$ isn't meaningful anyway. Moreover, it is not necessary to adjust the time configuration of $p_t$ either. Simply multiply $p_t$ with the the leads and lags of $x_{jt}$ directly.
Assume a binary treatment variable $x_{jt}$, such as a county level tax policy or whatever is of interest to you. Now say the policy is rolled out at different times in different counties. Here, $x_{jt}$ is just an indicator for whether the treatment 'switched on' (i.e., changed from 0 to 1) in county $j$ and year $t$. The equation below seems appropriate,
$$
\ln(y_{ijt}) = \alpha_j + \lambda_t + \sum_{k=-m}^{q}\gamma_k x_{j,t+k} + \sum_{k=-m}^q \tau_k x_{j,t+k} \times \ln(\mbox{p}_{t}) + \epsilon_{ijt},
$$
where we estimate some arbitrary number of $q$ leads and $m$ lags of the policy variable. I altered the limits of the summation, but feel free to keep the $a$ and $-a$ convention if that works for you. $\gamma_k$ denotes a series of lead and lag parameters. To assess the moderating influence of $p_t$ on the relationship between $x$ and $y$, simply interact $p_t$ with each of the policy indicators. The $\tau_k$ parameters will offer some insight into how this effect is evolving before and after the policy change.
I simulated some data in R to demonstrate what this looks like in the real world. The full data frame consists of 5 counties observed over 10 years. Each county has a different "start year" as indicated by the first_treat variable. The event_time column is just the difference between first_year and year. Each treated county is now centered around their first (immediate) policy year (event_time = 0). The abridged data frame below shows two treated counties over a 10-year period. If you estimate separate dummy variables for each value of event_time it will automatically generate the leads and lags for you. Note that in a setting where a subset of counties never adopt the new policy, they remain equal to 0 in all periods. For the sake of this explanation, say all counties adopts the policy, but they vary in the timing of the first adoption.
## Variables:

# county      = county identifier
# year        = year identifier
# t_group     = treatment indicator
# post        = post-treatment indicator
# first_treat = first year treatment starts
# event_time  = first_treat - year 
# cov_t       = covariate (time-varying but stable across counties)
# y           = continuous outcome

# A tibble: 50 × 8
   county  year t_group  post first_treat event_time cov_t     y
   <fct>  <int>   <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>      <dbl> <dbl>
 1 1       2010       1     0        2013 3             14  83.0
 2 1       2011       1     0        2013 2             14  86.1
 3 1       2012       1     0        2013 1             12  78.8
 4 1       2013       1     1        2013 0             11  79.8
 5 1       2014       1     1        2013 -1            11  75.1
 6 1       2015       1     1        2013 -2            19  87.0
 7 1       2016       1     1        2013 -3            17  86.2
 8 1       2017       1     1        2013 -4            15  82.5
 9 1       2018       1     1        2013 -5            18  80.6
10 1       2019       1     1        2013 -6            15  72.7
11 2       2010       1     0        2014 4             14  89.9
12 2       2011       1     0        2014 3             14  71.4
13 2       2012       1     0        2014 2             12  83.2
14 2       2013       1     0        2014 1             11  86.1
15 2       2014       1     1        2014 0             11  83.9
16 2       2015       1     1        2014 -1            19  79.4
17 2       2016       1     1        2014 -2            17  72.1
18 2       2017       1     1        2014 -3            15  86.2
19 2       2018       1     1        2014 -4            18  80.5
20 2       2019       1     1        2014 -5            15  81.0

If cov_t has the same pattern within each county, as $p_t$ suggests, then it's collinear with the year fixed effects. In other words, once we adjust for the aggregate level time shocks affecting all counties in the same way, then inputting cov_t into the model, or any lead or lag of it, offers no advantage. Even if you estimated cov_t first in terms of variable precedence, most software packages compromise by dropping a year.
In short, do not lead or lag $p_t$. In the presence of the county and year fixed effects, the main effect associated with $p_t$ isn't even estimable, nor relevant for the question your pursuing. Simply interact the leads and lags of the policy variable $x_{jt} $with $p_t$ directly. The evolution of the $\tau_k$'s is what matters.
I recommended some R code below. The base R solution will work just fine, although the output is a little messy. In my opinion, the fixest package offers a cleaner output, and their ref = ... option allows you to manually select the reference year.
# base R

lm(log(y) ~ as.factor(county) + as.factor(year) + factor(event_time) * log(cov_t), data = ...)

# library(fixest)

feols(log(y) ~ event_time + i(event_time, log(cov_t), ref = 1) | county + year, panel.id = ~county + year, data = ...)


Wow, this is perfect.I couldn't upvote due to no reputation points, but I just accepted the answer. Thanks a lot for your insights.
